# how to format data with extJs

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

This is my first question in StackOverflow. I'm trying to format a number into date. I get date data like `'20210728'` from sql.
So I want to show the date on the web like `'2021-07-28'`.  I have already made some code to format number into date format, but I want to know if there is any other ways to format data better.

Here is my code:

[image]

I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Comment: [please post your code as text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). And also no need to state that this is your first question in SO. Anyways happy coding and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

If the format will always be `yyyyMMdd` then you could just use a regular expression to add in the dashes if all that you're wanting is to display the date as text. See this regex example for an explanation on how this works: https://regex101.com/r/KGv2iy/1

If you need an actual JS date object, then you could just use that string in a `new Date()` call.

Using the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` method allows you to do all kinds of formatting on actual Date objects. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

And lastly, but certainly not least, is the moment.js library https://momentjs.com/ that makes it really easy to format your Date objects

```js
const dateNumber = 20210728;
const regex = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
const str = dateNumber.toString();
const subst = `$1-$2-$3`;
const dateString = str.replace(regex, subst);
const newDate = new Date(dateString);

const momentDate = moment(dateNumber.toString()).format(`YY-MM-DD`);

console.log({dateString: dateString, newDate: newDate, momentDate: momentDate})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use ExtJs internal methods:

```
Ext.Date.format(Ext.Date.parse('20210607','Ymd'),'Y-m-d')
```